# How To Install linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 on Debian?

Tags: debian

I tried to migrate my google cloud platform VM from my account to client account using cloudendure, but hooked up with an error. When I contacted cloudendure support team with the error log, they told me to install **linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64** (that corresponds to the 4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 kernel that I have running).

I tried to install it using the following command

`sudo apt install -t jessie-backports linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 linux-image-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 -s`

But I got the following error response

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64'
```

In my installation, I couldn't find the required package as you can see bellow

```
@instance-1:~$ apt-cache search linux-header
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-all - All header files for Linux 3.16 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-all-amd64 - All header files for Linux 3.16 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64 - Header files for Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common - Common header files for Linux 3.16.0-4
linux-headers-amd64 - Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-all - All header files for Linux 4.9 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-all-amd64 - All header files for Linux 4.9 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-common - Common header files for Linux 4.9.0-0.bpo.1
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-common-rt - Common header files for Linux 4.9.0-0.bpo.1-rt
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.9.0-0.bpo.1-rt-amd64
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-all - All header files for Linux 4.9 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-all-amd64 - All header files for Linux 4.9 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-common - Common header files for Linux 4.9.0-0.bpo.2
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-common-rt - Common header files for Linux 4.9.0-0.bpo.2-rt
linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.9.0-0.bpo.2-rt-amd64
linux-headers-4.8.0-2-common-grsec - Common header files for Linux 4.8.0-2-grsec
linux-headers-4.8.0-2-grsec-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.8.0-2-grsec-amd64
linux-headers-grsec-amd64 - Header files for Linux amd64 configuration, grsec featureset (meta-package)
linux-headers-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux rt-amd64 configuration (meta-package)
```

Please, how do I install this required package in other to continue my work of migration?

In addition, am running **Debian 8.7**. I have the following images installed:

```
@instance-1:~$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64 3.16.39-1+deb8u1 amd64 Linux 3.16 for 64-bit PCs
ii linux-image-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64-unsigned 4.7.5-1~bpo8+2 amd64 Linux 4.7 for 64-bit PCs
ii linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 4.9.2-2~bpo8+1 amd64 Linux 4.9 for 64-bit PCs (signed)
ii linux-image-amd64 4.9+78~bpo8+1 amd64 Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

and the running kernel is

```
instance-1:~$ uname -a
Linux instance-1 4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.7.5-1~bpo8+2 (2016-10-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the appropriate version from [snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64/) and install that manually, along with any dependencies. (It's also possible to set up an `apt` repository for the relevant snapshot but it's probably not worth it here.)

Given that you're running version 4.7.5-1~bpo8+2, here are the files you need to download and install:

- [linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64_4.7.5-1~bpo8+2_amd64.deb](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20161005T222159Z/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64_4.7.5-1%7Ebpo8%2B2_amd64.deb)
- [linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-common_4.7.5-1~bpo8+2_amd64.deb](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20161005T222159Z/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-common_4.7.5-1%7Ebpo8%2B2_amd64.deb)
- [linux-kbuild-4.7_4.7.5-1~bpo8+2_amd64.deb](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20161005T222159Z/pool/main/l/linux/linux-kbuild-4.7_4.7.5-1%7Ebpo8%2B2_amd64.deb)
- [linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86_4.7.5-1~bpo8+2_amd64.deb](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20161005T222159Z/pool/main/l/linux/linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86_4.7.5-1%7Ebpo8%2B2_amd64.deb)

After installing all four of these, you may need to run `apt-get install -f` to fix any further missing dependencies (*e.g.* the compiler).

Note that you should really upgrade to the currently-available kernel from backports. To do this, along with the headers, in a way that will keep you up-to-date as newer kernels are made available, install `linux-image-amd64` and `linux-headers-amd64` from backports:

```
apt-get install -t jessie-backports linux-{image,headers}-amd64
```

Comment: GREAT work! Thank you very much for your time, effor, energy and contribution. My work is now in progress because of you.